# How to make a segue from one viewcontroller to itself without resetting its current state?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I did actually make a segue from my viewcontroller to itself by using a hidden button and then another one that makes the segue. Just for the sake of clarification, say I want to change the view bg color by using a segue. The issue here is that the view returns to its first state as if I run it again because it goes through the viewdidload and the viewdidappear and so. 
Is there a way or a workaround that I can utilize to continue from the last state of my view?

What do I need to add to this code for example:

```
- (IBAction)changeColor:(id)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"changeC" sender:self];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    ViewController* controller = [segue destinationViewController];

    controller.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];   
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to segue to the same VC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not even going to ask why you would ever actually want to do that, but you could just have a BOOL like shouldReloadView, and set that to NO in `prepareForSegue:`. Then, within `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear` just check for that BOOL before doing any setup.

Comment: Thank you sfeuerstein for your quick reply. I know the idea that I'm trying to implement here is kinda weird but I'm doing it for the sake of learning. I'm sorry I'll have to bother you for more explanation if possible because I'm a newbie.

Comment: In your .h file add: @property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL shouldReloadView;

Then in your prepareForSegue method, add: controller.shouldReloadView = NO;

Finally, in your viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear check if _shouldReloadView, and only set up the view again if the BOOL is true.

Hope that helps!

Comment: As far as better practice, you could add a method that would hide the view within the viewController, reload whatever you need to reload in it (such as changing the color), then show it again. That way you don't even have to mess with segues when reloading your view.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to add a color variable to you header file:

```
 @property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor *backgroundColor;
```

Then customize the init function in the implementation file to require a UIColor.

Then forget about segues just do the following.

```
  YourViewController *viewController = [[YourViewController alloc] initWithBackgroundColor:[UIColor someColor]];

  [self.navigationController pushViewController:YourViewController animation:YES];
```

Et voila.

Comment: Thank you Mikael but this is not what I'm looking to achieve. It's not about changing color. It's like having a webview that is created in viewdidload and then appears on your view every time you run your project. I want to be able to reload my viewcontroller via a segue and hide that webview for example. It's not something I'm working on, it's the idea itself whether it's possible or it doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

@sfeuerstein is correct
based on his suggestion

```
- (IBAction)changeColor:(id)sender {
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"changeC" sender:self];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
   ViewController* controller = [segue destinationViewController];

   controller.state = YES;  // set bool value in your controller state
}
```

make a check in your view controller

```
-(void)ViewDidLoad{  

if(NewState){
    controller.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor]; 
   }
else{
   controller.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor]; 
   }
}
```

but i still dont know , why you are trying to do something like this . its not good approach.

Comment: Thank you pawan. Even though I'm a newbie, I can see that this is not a good approach but I'm trying to explore it to see if I might make use of it in my app.